# publish public posts to facebook fan page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, koala

I'm trying to post to my facebook fan page as the admin of the page via below code snippet:

```
require 'koala'
@page_graph.get_object('me') # I'm a page
@page_graph.get_connection('me', 'feed') # the page's wall
@page_graph.put_wall_post('post on page wall') # post as page
@page_graph.put_connections(page_id, 'feed', :message => "post mesage..", :picture => picture_url, :link => link_url)
```

But the public posts only visible to me and are hidden from all other users who accessing the page.

Can some one help how can I publish public posts on fan page wall to be visible for all users? Thanks.

Comment: i am facing the same problem in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turn on  Facebook app and all its live features available to the general public through app dashboard

Answer (score 1):

Go to `developers.facebook.com`

select your APP

On your App page

Select Stats and review

Check yes to  the option
"Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?"